# Problem with `escapeinside` when implementing pascal code

Tags: minted

Actually I’m working on some **pascal** documentation but I noticed that some features that need `escapeinside` option did not work well. Surprisingly, when I changed the language (to **phyton** or another) and all things are fine.

Here my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% source: tcolorbox package (p. 16)
\newtcbox{\mybox}[1][red]{on line,
    arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!50!black,
    boxsep=0pt,left=1pt,right=1pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,
    boxrule=0pt,bottomrule=1pt,toprule=1pt}

\begin{document}

% source: minted package (p. 22)
\noindent phyton code
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=??]{py}
def f(x):
    y = x?\colorbox{green}{**}?2
    y = x?\mybox[green]{**}?2
return y
\end{minted}

\noindent pascal code
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=??]{pascal}
    a ?\colorbox{green}{:=}? b + c
    a ?\mybox[green]{:=}? b + c
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: The documentation of `minted` about `escapeinside` mentions that it is fragile with some Pygmentize lexers.